# add_post_meta Multi value not working when i try to add them using loop

Tags: php, wordpress

At WordPress, I use a loop to add multiple meta values at a meta field. But every time it adds the lat value.

Here is my code:

```
$value = array("red", "green", "yellow")
foreach ( $value as $item ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, "_color", $item );
}
```

Every time after saving it save only yellow.

NOTE: This code works on my server but when I try to a client-server, it is behaving like this.

Wordpress Version: 4.7

Please help me.

Comment: have you check in the DB? and how can you say it is only adding only the last element ?

Comment: ok , when i run
    <code>
     $value = get_post_meta($post_id, "_color");
    </code>

$value have only one value, like 
    <code>array("yellow");</code>

Answer (score 0):

Lets try by adding fourth parameter as "false".

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, "_color", $item, false );
```

I know, the fourth parameter is 'false' by default, but lets try it once, because your value is overwritten every time by the same key, therefore it is storing the last value i.e. "Yellow".

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
add_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', 'XYZ');
$return = get_post_meta($post_id, 'counter_meta', true );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($return);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$post_id = 12;
$value = array("red", "green", "yellow")
foreach ( $value as $item ) {
    add_post_meta( $post_id, "_color", $item );
}
```

Comment: I use this but no luck, same as previous. This is not happening with all server. This is happening with some server.